# creating random int by rand

Tags: c++, random

I want to write a cryptography application and need a function to create an iv. to create that iv i want to use rand() (even if thats not secure, i want to rewrite most parts of the code later anyway). That leads me to my problem: rand() does only return values from 0 to RAND_MAX (on my machine RAND_MAX is 32767), and i don't know if i could use code like this if RAND_MAX >= 65535:

```
void generate_iv(unsigned char* char_buf, int len){
    union { //treat char_buf like a short_buf
        unsigned char* char_buf;
        unsigned short* short_buf;
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len / 2; i++){ //fill short_buf with random values
        short_buf[i] = (unsigned short) rand();
    }
    if (len & 0x01){ //could not fill char_buf with 2-byte short values completely
        char_buf[len - 1] = (unsigned char) rand();
    }
}
```

Of course this will compile easily on every machine, but it wont work on machines where RAND_MAX < 65535, because then the function does not fill every bit.

Code that would always work is:

```
void generate_iv(unsigned char* char_buf, int len){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        char_buf = (unsigned char) rand();
    }
}
```

This code should work without problems, but it is not effective as the code above.
My question is: Is there any optimum beetween effiency and portability in this case and is there maybe a more secury way (which could be easy to implement) to produce random numbers or a way to get random numbers with a constant size?

Comment: If you're writing a cryptography application, I certainly wouldn't recommend `rand`. There's a nice shiny `<random>` header that performs much better and doesn't have a possibly horrendously low maximum value (even `INT_MAX` with a 32-bit `int` is low when 64-bit is supported).

Comment: You shouldn't use `rand` for cryptography. Take a look at the C++11 [random number generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library.

Comment: like i said, i just wanted to use any random function to test the program, rand() was just the first that came to my mind. i am aware of the security lack that gets created by using rand. so i am even happier that you showed me a solution to my problem and a whole new library to "explore".

Comment: i just compiled a program which includes <random> and my compiler (Mingw, g++) exited and said this feature is still experimental. can i really rely on this?

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, `rand()` is not secured, so I will refer to the problem at hand regardless of that issue.

Given that `rand()` generates a 15-bit number, and you want a 16-bit number, you can simply do:

```
int a = rand();
int b = rand()&1;
return a | (b<<15);
```

Or generally, given that `RAND_MAX < 0xFFFF` and that `RAND_MAX+1` is a power of 2:

```
int len = BIT_LEN(RAND_MAX);
int mask = (1<<(16-len))-1;
int a = rand();
int b = rand()&mask;
return a | (b<<len);
```

BTW, don't forget to seed the RNG with some random input at the beginning of your program, e.g.:

```
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```